# Is it possible for window.prompt to allow user input via a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'd like the user to be able to choose from a variety of colleges. Is this possible via `window.prompt`? If not, is there a plugin or something that allows for this?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080184/how-to-add-columns-rows-to-a-table-in-rails for the context of why I ask.

Comment: `window.prompt`? You don't use that in production! `<select>` is a tag which is exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Not from a prompt, but you can use something that looks like it. You can either make one yourself or use something like jQuery Dialog

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/